# Stackoverflow error on Javascript toJSON custom method

Tags: javascript, json, oop, design-patterns

**Scenario**

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12690175/1083946) I realized that I could create object starting from a JSON literal.

So I guessed that I could do the opposite just using this useful JSON method:
`JSON.stringify(myObject)`.

So I did as follow:

```
function MyObject(id, value, desc)
{
  this.id = id;
  this.value = value;
  this.desc = desc;
  this.toJSON = function()
  {
    return JSON.stringify(this);
  }

}
```

But when I run this stuff ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bkPmT/)) a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error occurs.

After googling a bit, I found two references that explain this behaviour:

- the [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior) method at MDN.
- the [JSON in Javascript](http://www.json.org/js.html) article at JSON.org

If I get right, `.toJSON` overrides the `.stringify`. So if the first one calls the second one a loop is generated.

**Questions**

1. (general) Why this design choice? `toJSON` is a kind of reserved of special keyword?
2. (specific) I solved the stackoverflow bug changing the `.toJSON` name into `.display`. Not so elegant. Is there another solution?

Comment: +1 for using the stackoverflow keyword.  No, kidding, it's a good question.

Comment: @ADC Remember to accept your open questions.

Comment: Why do you use a custom `toJSON` method if there is nothing special?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1, is `toJSON` reserved?**

I'm not sure if it reserved, but for example the native Date object uses toJSON to create a stringified date representation:

```
(new Date()).toJSON();           // -> "2012-10-20T01:58:21.427Z"
JSON.stringify({d: new Date()}); // -> {"d":"2012-10-20T01:58:21.427Z"}"
```

**Question 2, an easy solution:**

create your custom stringify function that ignores toJSON methods (you may add it to the already existing global `JSON`):

```
JSON.customStringify = function (obj) {

    var fn = obj.toJSON;
    obj.toJSON = undefined;
    var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
    obj.toJSON = fn;
    return json;
}
```

now it's very easy to use in all your objects:

```
function MyObject(id, value, desc)
{
  this.id = id;
  this.value = value;
  this.desc = desc;
  this.toJSON = function()
  {
    return JSON.customStringify(this);
  }
}
```

To make it even more easy additionally add:

```
JSON.customStringifyMethod = function () {

    return JSON.customStringify(this);
}
```

Now your objects might look like:

```
function MyObject(id, value, desc)
{
  this.id = id;
  this.value = value;
  this.desc = desc;
  this.toJSON = JSON.customStringifyMethod;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Think it's because `toJSON` is semi reserved: `stringify` will check the object and see if it's has a method called `toJSON` and then try to call it to string the result.

---

A workaround can be: (Not sure about the reliablity of this code)

```
var obj = {
    value: 1,
    name: "John",
    toJSON: function() {
        var ret,
            fn = this.toJSON;

        delete this.toJSON;

        ret = JSON.stringify(this);

        this.toJSON = fn;

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
obj.toJSON(); // "{\"value\":1,\"name\":\"John\"}"
obj.lastName = "Smith";
obj.toJSON(); // "{\"value\":1,\"name\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Smith\"}"
```

---

Maybe using a clousure is a little prettier: (And then I think I can say it's safe)

```
var obj = {
    value: 1,
    name: "John",
    toJSON: (function() {
        function fn() {
            var ret;
            delete this.toJSON;

            ret = JSON.stringify(this);

            this.toJSON = fn;

            return ret;
        }
        return fn;
    })()
}
```

---

So after reading @filmor's comment i thoght about another way to handle this. Not that pretty but it works.

Using [Function.caller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) I can detect if `fn` is called using `JSON.stringify`

```
var obj = {
    value: 1,
    name: "John",
    toJSON: (function() {
        return function fn() {
            var ret;

            delete this.toJSON;

            ret = JSON.stringify(this);

            if ( fn.caller === JSON.stringify ) {
                ret = JSON.parse( ret );
            }

            this.toJSON = fn;

            return ret;
        }
    })()
}
```

Comment: Found that out at roughly the same time as you (after crashing Firefox during the course ;)). One comment: If you do it like this you break normal `JSON.stringify(obj)`, since it will interpret the object as a string and escape and add surrounding " chars.

Comment: @filmor I ran into the same problem. But think I found a solution using `fn.caller`

Comment: Interesting, but quite a lot of stuff just to use `toJSON` intead of `display` :). Note that there is a `non standard` remark in the `Function.caller` page. Anyway, an elegant solution.