# how to handle jsonarray response using angular js? i am getting

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I am getting this error:

> Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Repeater: session in privateKeyList key: string:I

This is my JavaScript code:

```
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                      $scope.privateKeyList = data.privateKeyList;

                    $scope.totalPrivKey=data.totalPrivateKey;
```

This is my JSP code:

```
       <tbody  ng-repeat="session in privateKeyList">
          <tr>
                                <td>{{session.ptID}}</td>
                                <td>{{session.encID}}</td>
                                <td>{{session.doctorID}}</td>

         </tr>
```

This is the response in JSON string:

```
 {
  "privateKeyList":
     "[\"{key1:9315, key2:27108, key3:122 }\",
    \"{key1:9315, key2:27108, key3:122}\"]",

 "totalPrivateKey": 888  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `track by $index` with `ng-repeat` and Use ng-repeat with `<tr>` tag.

```
<tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="session in privateKeyList" track by $index>
                                <td>{{session.ptID}}</td>
                                <td>{{session.encID}}</td>
                                <td>{{session.doctorID}}</td>

         </tr>
</tbody>
```

Use the `track by $index` with `ng-repeat`
Example

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in collection track by $id(obj)">
  {{obj.prop}}
</div>

<div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43] track by $index">
  {{n}}
</div>
```

for more know
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 1):

## By ref and by value

You are not creating a separate object for each item in your array. your array just holds a ref.

To get around this you can go to your repeat and add

```
ng-repeat="session in privateKeyList track by $index"
```

## Objects

Should you need a new object for whatever reason you should just create it before you push to the array with `Object.create`

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690107/clone-object-without-reference-javascript/12690175#comment56694005_12690175) is a link to a question that explains it.