# Updating one object in javascript 2d array updates every single object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I declare a 2d array in javascript as follows:

```
cell = {visited:false, left:true, top:true, right:true, bottom:true}

cells = new Array(10);

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) //Initiate 2d cells array.
{
    cells[i] = new Array(cell,cell,cell,cell,cell,cell,cell,cell,cell,cell);
}
```

Later in the code I update one object in the array:

```
cells[0][0].visited = true;
```

However after I do this every visited attribute of every object in the array is marked true.

Comment: You have only a single cell, referenced repeatedly in the array. You either need to clone them, or create each cell in the loop.

Comment: You're code is putting the exact same object in the array 10 times. The array will contain 10 references to the same single object.

Comment: How do I create an array of separate cell objects?

Comment: By creating each cell on its own, or cloning the initial state.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Like this? cells[i] = new Array({visited:false, left:true, top:true, right:true, bottom:true}, '', ''.....);

Comment: @Globaz i just put an example on answers

Answer (score 0):

As @Pointy said, your code have this reference problem. You can resolve this with `Object.create()` building a "clone" of the object:

```js
cell = {visited:false, left:true, top:true, right:true, bottom:true}

cells = new Array(10);

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) //Initiate 2d cells array.
{
    cells[i] = new Array(
      Object.create(cell),
      Object.create(cell),
      Object.create(cell),
      Object.create(cell),
      Object.create(cell),
      Object.create(cell),
      Object.create(cell),
      Object.create(cell),
      Object.create(cell),
      Object.create(cell)
    );
}

cells[0][0].visited = true;
```

See also [Clone Object without reference javascript [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690107/clone-object-without-reference-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I needed to initiate the array with separate objects not the same "cell":

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) //Initiate 2d cells array.
{
cells[i] = new Array({visited:false, left:true, top:true, right:true,                     bottom:true},
    {visited:false, left:true, top:true, right:true, bottom:true},
    {visited:false, left:true, top:true, right:true, bottom:true},
    {visited:false, left:true, top:true, right:true, bottom:true},
    {visited:false, left:true, top:true, right:true, bottom:true},
    {visited:false, left:true, top:true, right:true, bottom:true},
    {visited:false, left:true, top:true, right:true, bottom:true},
    {visited:false, left:true, top:true, right:true, bottom:true},
    {visited:false, left:true, top:true, right:true, bottom:true},
    {visited:false, left:true, top:true, right:true, bottom:true});
}
```