# Assign value not reference in javascript

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

I am having a little problem assigning objects in javascript.

take a look at this sample code that reproduces my problem.

```
var fruit = {
   name: "Apple"
};

var vegetable = fruit;
vegetable.name = "potatoe";
console.log(fruit);
```

it logs

```
Object {name: "potatoe"}
```

How can I assign the value not the reference of an object to another object?

Comment: Make a copy of the object - one simple way is: `var vegetable = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(fruit));`

Comment: *How can I assign the value not the reference of an object to another object?*. You can't JavaScript doesn't work like that. Your only option is to copy the object as @tymeJV says.

Comment: Check this SO question out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690107/clone-object-without-reference-javascript

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
var fruit = {
   name: "Apple"
};

var vegetable = Object.assign({}, fruit);
vegetable.name = "potatoe";
console.log(fruit);
```

Comment: Note, this doesn't assign the value (as the OP wants) but copies it into a new object. Subtle but sometimes important distinction

Comment: can you please explain a little this `assign` call? what is that empty object in the first argument?

Comment: @MubasharAbbas [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: Object.assign({}, obj); you can see more in: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/assign