# Rotating a moving image with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm having some problems causing in image to rotate properly after it follows the cursor. I think that it is rotating based on it's original location but I am not sure.

Any chance to make it rotate a full 360 degrees regardless of its final location?

Code:

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  /*duration determines the speed of the animation (in this case, the speed to which prgm follows)*/
  $("#image").stop().animate({
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
  }, {
    duration: 5000
  });
});


let box = document.querySelector(".box");
let boxBoundingRect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
let boxCenter = {
  x: boxBoundingRect.left + boxBoundingRect.width / 2,
  y: boxBoundingRect.top + boxBoundingRect.height / 2
};

document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
      let angle = Math.atan2(e.pageX - boxCenter.x, -(e.pageY - boxCenter.y) )*(180 / Math.PI);
        box.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}deg)`;
      })
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: black;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="box" id="image"> </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, be sure to mark it as the selected answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A must-know about coding:

When coding, declaring a variable like the following works differently than you think it does.

```js
var var1 = 2;
var var2 = var1;
```

Instead of `var2` always being the value of `var1`, it just sets `var2` to whatever `var1` is at the moment.

Which means setting `var1` to 3 will still keep `var2` at 2.

###### Confused? Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840293/setting-a-variable-equal-to-another-variable#:%7E:text=The%20really%20short%20answer%20to,linkage%20between%20the%20two%20variables.) to see what I mean! (To be honest, this confused me more)

### How does this relate?

In the following line, you do the following:

```js
let boxBoundingRect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
let boxCenter = {
  x: boxBoundingRect.left + boxBoundingRect.width / 2,
  y: boxBoundingRect.top + boxBoundingRect.height / 2
};
```

But when the position changes, those values don't change. Rather, they stay the same.

### What do you do?

In this function:

```js
document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  let angle = Math.atan2(e.pageX - boxCenter.x, -(e.pageY - boxCenter.y)) * (180 / Math.PI);
  box.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}deg)`;
})
```

Recalculate the bounding box so it looks like the following:

```js
document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  boxBoundingRect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
  boxCenter = {
    x: boxBoundingRect.left + boxBoundingRect.width / 2,
    y: boxBoundingRect.top + boxBoundingRect.height / 2
  };
  let angle = Math.atan2(e.pageX - boxCenter.x, -(e.pageY - boxCenter.y)) * (180 / Math.PI);
  box.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}deg)`;
})
```

## Snippet

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  /*duration determines the speed of the animation (in this case, the speed to which prgm follows)*/
  $("#image").stop().animate({
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
  }, {
    duration: 5000
  });
});


let box = document.querySelector(".box");
let boxBoundingRect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
let boxCenter = {
  x: boxBoundingRect.left + boxBoundingRect.width / 2,
  y: boxBoundingRect.top + boxBoundingRect.height / 2
};

document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  boxBoundingRect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
  boxCenter = {
    x: boxBoundingRect.left + boxBoundingRect.width / 2,
    y: boxBoundingRect.top + boxBoundingRect.height / 2
  };
  let angle = Math.atan2(e.pageX - boxCenter.x, -(e.pageY - boxCenter.y)) * (180 / Math.PI);
  box.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}deg)`;
})
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: black;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="box" id="image"> </div>
</body>
```