# Side effects in Mocha tests in for-loop

Tags: for-loop, mocha.js, chai

I am seeing unexpected results with the following Mocha tests, and I cannot figure out why. I have a bunch of objects from a web store that get translated into an Order object. I'm trying to run many relatively simple attribute comparisons, so I decided to loop over my tests.

```
import assert from 'assert'
import {expect} from 'chai'
...
const test_orders = [ <a bunch of objects> ]

function order_test(order, expected_values) {
    describe(`Order#new ${expected_values.expected_package_type}`, () => {
    ...
    })
}
for (var i = 0; i < test_orders.length; i++){
    let translated_order = {}, order = {};
    translated_order = new TranslateOrder(test_orders[i].untranslated_params)
    order = new Order(translated_order)
    order_test(order, test_orders[i]);
}
```

The problem is that I get different test results depending on the order in which the objects appear in `test_orders`, which tells me I am getting unexpected side effects. I just can't figure out where they are coming from. Any help would be much appreciated!

If the

```
translated_order = new TranslateOrder(test_orders[i].untranslated_params)
order = new Order(translated_order)
```

bit is the culprit, as I suspect, I would love to know what to do differently. It's a bit involved, but in one sentence, `TranslateOrder` creates an object from a JSON string, and `Order` is the model object that I use in my React app downstream.

I did try `order = new Order(Object.assign({}, translated_order))` thinking that was the origin of the side effects, but the results were the same.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was a side effect inside my `Order` object. Inside the `Order` object, I was importing a data structure object and altering its values. I should have been making a copy of the data structure with `var data = Object.assign({}, imported_data)` instead of `var data = imported_data`.

Rookie mistake! If you've gotten here and you don't understand, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690107/clone-object-without-reference-javascript).