# React const changing value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constants

How is it possible, I'm creating a const to get the old messages from my chat, so I can know if has a new message comming from the database or something like that, but there is something wierd with my code, the const is changing value

```
const oldMessages = this.state.messages.slice();

// Console
console.log(oldMessages[oldMessages.length - 1]);
// Prints {name: "André", message: "asds", who: "Y", sending: true, local_key: 232, …}

newMessages.map((message, key) => {
    // Here I don't even call the const
    if (message.local_key != undefined) {
        const i = messages.map((i) => {
            return i.local_key
        }).indexOf(message.local_key);
        if (i >= 0) {
            // messages.splice(i, 1);
            messages[i].id = message.id;
            messages[i].sending = false;
            messages[i].local_key = null;
            newMessages.splice(key, 1);
            //
            // Limpar chave do banco
            //
        } else {
            newMessages[key].local_key = null;
        }
    }
    if (newMessages[key] != undefined) {
        newMessages[key].animate = true;
    }
});

// Console
console.log(oldMessages[oldMessages.length - 1]);
// Prints {name: "André", message: "asds", who: "Y", sending: false, local_key: null, …}
```

You can see, I don't even call the variables, except in the consoles

Has something to do with the reference?

PS: `messages` is a reference of `this.state.messages` too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const` doesn't do what you think it does.

`const` prevents re-assigment of a variable:

```
const arr = []; 

arr.push(1); // works

console.log(arr); // [1]

arr = []; // whoops
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that, but I dont mutate the variable in the code, it's being mutated by the reference? I mean, `b = 1; const a = b; b = 2` it will change the value of a?

Comment: You have to know that objects in javascript are always passed as references. So: `const obj = {hello: 1}; const arr = [obj]; const newArray = arr.slice(); newArray[0].hello = 1337;` will in fact change `obj`.

Comment: How can I prevent it?

Comment: @SpaceDogCS You have to copy the object completely.

Comment: Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690107/clone-object-without-reference-javascript

Answer (score 3):

One thing to know about `const` is that

> Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let
>   statement. The value of a constant cannot change through
>   re-assignment, and it can't be redeclared.

In your case you are not reassigning the const variable, but mutating its original value which is possible

What you are looking for is an `Immutable` data which doesn't change it value but creates a new reference of the original data and updates it. Look into libraries such as [`Immutable-JS`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that, but I dont mutate the variable in the code, it's being mutated by the reference? I mean, `b = 1; const a = b; b = 2` it will change the value of a?

Comment: @SpaceDogCS, no It wont because number and strings are Immutable in javascript