# Prepare variables of context B in context A and resolve them inside context B

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Currently I'm trying to make repeating Ajax-Calls dynamic so my code gets better manageable. While doing so I encountered that I sometimes need dynamic data-attributes and -values. There is always just one data-value that changes, the other parameters stay the same. Doing so I could easily chain promises.

So here is an example of what I use as template for those Ajax-Calls:

```
var prepareAjax = {
    iterateValues: [1230,1280,4000,9000],
    ajaxOptions: [{
        timeout: 10000,
        type: "GET",
        data: `{
            param1: item,
            param2: obj.sessionId,
            param3: 1
        }`,     
        url: 'https://someurl.tld/target'
    }],
    sessionId: '<somestring>'
};
```

After this object I'm calling a function that should extract the `ajaxOptions` from the object like so:

```
function fetchChain(obj)=>{

    var ajaxPromises    = [], tempObj;

    obj.iterateValues.map((item, index)=> {

        tempObj         = obj.ajaxOptions[0];
        tempObj.data    = eval('('+tempObj.data+')');

        ajaxPromises.push(new Promise(
            (resolve, reject)=>{

                namespace.fetchData(tempObj);

            }
        );
    }
}
```

What I'm doing here is creating a promise and Ajax-Call for every `ìterateValue`. Then I'm using eval (yes, evil) to resolve the variables of the current context (`fetchChain`) and feed it to `fetchData`. The functions are executed withhin a namespace, so I'm calling them with `namespace.fetchChain(prepareAjax)` in example.

**The problem**

This example only works for one iteration since eval also seems to change `obj` permanently, even if I only eval/modify the `tempObj`, but obviously I want to reuse the template on every iteration. The only value that needs to be resolved is `item`, the parameters stay the same.

I also know `new Function()` is a better alternative to `eval` but I couldn't get it to work neither. What is more weird for me is that the function worked previously when eval'ing the data-attributes directly inside the Ajax-Call without using a preparation function like for `fetchChain()`. I'm stuck at this point, even after reading through several Answers on SO.

*For completeness, here is the fetchData function:*

```
function fetchData(obj)=>{

    // single ajax-calls should use a delay of 0
    obj.timeout = ((obj.timeout) ? obj.timeout : 10000),
    obj.retries = ((obj.retries) ? obj.retries : 5),
    obj.delay   = ((obj.delay) ? obj.delay : 1000),
    obj.type    = ((obj.type) ? obj.type : "GET"),
    obj.cnt     = ((obj.cnt) ? obj.cnt++ : 0);

    var sumDelay = obj.delay*(obj.cnt+1);

    setTimeout(()=>{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{

            return $.ajax(obj)
            .done((response)=>{

                return resolve(response);

            }).fail((error)=>{
                if(obj.cnt++ >= obj.retries){   
                    return resolve('Error');
                }
                fun.fetchData(obj);
            }).always((xd)=>{
            })
        })
    }, sumDelay)
}
```

**A Solution**

A solution I'm thinking of would be to prepare the object before feeding it to `fetchChain()`. Or to be more clear: in the context where `prepareAjax` gets created. Obviously I would prefer to directly handle this process inside `fetchChain()`.

**The Error**

When executing `fetchChain` like described above I'm getting the Error `Unexpected Identifier` on second iteration inside of the eval. ([object Object]) When debugging one could see the `obj` also changed its value for `data`.

Comment: This all looks very convoluted. Use `$.extend()` or native `Object.assign()` to merge objects. Your string data concept makes no sens at all to me. Also don't understand why `ajaxOptions` is array. Third issue is `$.ajax` itself returns a promise so wrapping in `new Promise` is an antl-pattern

Comment: Have a look at my answer, I already changed it to be used without eval, which negates the need to use template-strings and makes it more performant. Depending the extra promises I was able to remove all of them, but now I'm still having problems to delay the ajax-calls. When I wrap the ajax inside timeout, the promise doesn't gets passed through. A solution would be to add a separate promise, so not sure why you complain about it, since other SO-answers suggest what I did here. A timeout inside `.done()` doesn't help when chaining those calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to get rid of `eval()` I encountered the same problems as with eval → The original object always got changed too and this way all dynamic parameters were the same by the end of execution.

Turns out I had a fundamental misunderstanding on how '='-Operator works on objects. The objects doesn't get cloned and instead referenced. Since there are already better explained answers depending cloning objects in js, I'm just linking to one answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690107/clone-object-without-reference-javascript).

So what actually happens when I use `eval` on the `tempObj` is that it not only turns the template-string (data-attribute) of `tempObj` into an object, but also the template-string of `obj` it references to.

An easy approach to fix this problem, which seems to be commonly used:

```
var A = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Others, that doesn't work for me, due to how they work:

```
var A = Object.create(obj);
var A = Object.assign({},obj);
```

There are even more and better solutions, but just have a look at the link above.

Since I was asking for a solution utilizing `eval`, I'm giving an example which actually works and even supports multiple dynamic parameters and parameter-values.

```
function chainAjax(){
    var ajaxPromises = [], tempObj,
        iterateProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj.iterateValues[0])

    obj.iterateValues[0][iterateProps].map((item, index)=> {

        tempObj         = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj.ajaxOptions[0]));
        tempObj.data    = eval('('+tempObj.data+')');

        ajaxPromises.push(new Promise(
            (resolve, reject)=>{

                fetchData(tempObj).then(...)

            }
        ))
    })
    return Promise.all(ajaxPromises);
}
```

As template I would use something like this:

```
var prepareAjax = {
    iterateValues: [{
        appid: [1230,1280,4000,9000]
    }],
    ajaxOptions: [{
        timeout: 10000,
        type: "GET",
        data: `{
            appid: obj.iterateValues[0].appid[index],
            sessionid: '<somestring>',
            wizard_ajax: 1
        }`,     
        url: 'https://someurl.tld/target'
    }]
}
```

Last but not least an example on how to do this w/o eval:

```
function fetchChain(obj)=>{

    var ajaxPromises = tempArray = [], tempObject,
        iterateProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj.iterateValues[0]);

    // Prepare Data-Objects and resolve dynamic vars
    obj.iterateValues[0][iterateProps[0]].map((item, index)=> {
        tempObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj.ajaxOptions[0])); // clone trick

        iterateProps.map(keyname => 
            tempObject.data[keyname] = obj.iterateValues[0][keyname][index]
        )
        tempArray.push(tempObject);
    });

    tempArray.map((item, index)=> {;
        ajaxPromises.push(
            fun.fetchData(item).then((response)=>{
                return response;
            }); 
        )
    })

    return Promise.all(ajaxPromises);
}
```

And a slightly different template:

```
var prepareAjax = {
    iterateValues: [{ // matching property-names
        appid: [1230,1280,4000,9000]//═══════╗
    }],                             //       ║
    ajaxOptions: [{                 //       ║
        data: {                     //       ║
            appid: '',//<════════════════════╝
            sessionid: '<somestring>',
            wizard_ajax: 1
        },      
        url: 'https://somedomain.tld/target'
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would not you do something like to get that obj dynamically?

e.g.:

```
const iterateValues = [1230,1280,4000,9000];
const getAjaxOpts = value => {
  return {
    ajaxOptions: [{
      timeout: 10000,
      type: "GET",
      data: /* apply data here from value */    
      url: 'https://someurl.tld/target'
    }],
  sessionId: '<somestring>'
  };
};
```

and do iterations like:

```
const mapped = iterateValues.map(x => getAjaxOpts(x));
// do your promise things afterwards
```

Comment: The amount and names of data properties can change, else this would be easier to achieve. But granted your approach could be used before calling `fetchChain()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "amount and names of data properties can change"? Can you please give us more details on that?

Comment: Let's say I've a data-object `{p1: sessionid, p2: obj.id[index]}` and another data-object `{p1:'abc',p2:${value}, p3: obj.id[index]}`. The amount of iterations depends on `iterateValues`. When I prepare those objects outside of `fetchData` I have to wrap them in backticks, else they would get resolved. Then you think "let's separate the one changing parameter" but `fetchData` cannot know (w/o a second parameter) where to insert this changing value while iterating. Is this better understandable? Else I'm giving a longer example if needed.

Comment: Hm, another idea would be to leave the one parameter that needs to be changed on iterations blank and replace it with the current map item. This way I wouldn't need to use eval. Maybe u meant this?

Comment: I would suggest to use whole object that you want to pass. By guessing "either this changes or that" is a bad practice IMO. I would pass whole object instead by myself. Because what you're trying to do, instead of being simple, it becomes more complex and often will lead confusions afterwards. EDIT: not to mention the 'eval'. You should ALWAYS avoid it at any cost (because there always are options at 99% of cases).

Comment: You're right, but my use-case is special in a way where I can tell that most, if not all ajax requests share the same structure. I rewrote the function I posted as answer to be used without eval, I just had to add 2 more maps/loops to prepare the objects and I'm matching the property-names of `iterateValues` with propery-names inside `data`. IMO using a config like this is self explaining and the underlying functions doesn't need to be touched anymore. Most importantly I can unify repetitive error-handling now.

Comment: Not totally understood what you're trying to achieve by that, but I would really avoid writing something like that though. I don't see any problems by transforming those variables into objects you want there, e.g. `iterateValues.map(x => ({ appid: x, session_id: '<some string>', ...etc });` and pass it to `getAjaxOpts`. EDIT: by noting that you want 'more manageable code' -- what you're trying to do is not manageable. What if properties change? What if you want to add more properties? What if you want some certain prop only for 1 item and not for the rest? It will get difficult time by time.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the changes I made by your suggestions, maybe it is getting more clear now. The `iterateValues[0][propertyname[0]]` must match  `data[propertyname]` and this way I can replace multiple parameters if needed on every iteration and I always use corresponding arrays anyway. Thanks for your help btw, much appreciated! :)

Comment: Well, you know your thing more ;d thanks and have a good day!