# How to soft copy an object and all of the functions inside it?

Tags: javascript, object

Let's say i have an object that looks like this:

```
function object () {
     this.property = false;

     this.function = function () {
          return !property;
     }
}
```

Then i create a copy of an instance of this object like so:

```
let copy = JSON.Parse(JSON.stringify(object));
```

This only copies the properties of the object, not the functions, how do i do that?

Comment: See also [JavaScript cloned object loses its prototype functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10151216/215552)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, the linked question doesn't involve cloning object functions.